# Jupyterlab minimize navigation pane

Tags: jupyter

In JupyterLab, the navigation pane on the left side of the screen is very useful but takes a lot of real estate. Is there a way to hide it so that we can look at notebooks using the full width of the navigator window?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The answer to my own question, duh, is that you just click on the "Files" vertical tab. This action toggles the navigation pane.

Comment: I was completely confused by this as well. I was hunting around in the menus, looking for a little toggle on the dividing line (click and it would close/open), or if I could just drag the thing to collapse.

Comment: But is there a keyboard shortcut to hide/unhide it?

Comment: What is the "Files" vertical tab?

Comment: Jupyter Lab has a set of tabs, stacked vertically, that appear on the left side of the browser window. They used to contain words, since replaced by icons (tooltips are displayed if you hover over the icons). 
The first tab used to say "Files" and now it displays a folder icon. Clicking on the icon toggles the entire set of vertical tabs on/off (unhide/hide). I am not aware of a keyboard shortcut for this.

Answer (score 8):

show/hide left sidebar **shortcut** `Ctrl + B` or `Command + B` (Mac)

Comment: doesn't work for me. are you sure you're on JupyterLab?

Comment: @CarlosE `Command + B` for Mac users.